# Reversing the key values in a dictionary (advanced reverse string in Python)

Tags: python, reverse

So what I was trying to do was output the string "33k22k11k", which is just the last value followed by the reversed last key followed by the second last value followed by the second last reversed key and so on. I'm not sure how to get the reversed key value for the specific loop that I am in. From the code I currently I have, I get the output:

```
dict = {"k1":1, "k2":2, "k3":3}
current=""
current_k=""
for k,v in dict.items():
    for i in k:
        current_k=i+current_k
    current=str(v)+current_k+current
print(current)
print(current_k)
```

33k2k1k22k1k11k

3k2k1k

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted for the future references.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**

First of all, if you are on python < 3.6, `dict` does not keep the order of items. You might want to use `collections.OrderedDict` for your purpose.

```
d = {"k1":1, "k2":2, "k3":3}
d.keys()
# dict_keys(['k2', 'k1', 'k3'])
```

whereas,

```
d = OrderedDict()
d['k1'] = 1
d['k2'] = 2
d['k3'] = 3
d.keys()
# odict_keys(['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])
```

With our new `d`, you can either add the key and values and reverse it:

```
res = ''
for k, v in d.items():
    res += str(k) + str(v)
res[::-1]
# '33k22k11k'
```

or reversely iterate:

```
res = ''
for k, v in reversed(d.items()):
    res +=  str(v)[::-1] + str(k)[::-1]
res
# '33k22k11k'
```

Comment: No. Python 3.6 and up have built-in `dict()` ordered.

Comment: @iBug I'm aware of the change, but since OP didn't specify the python version, `OrderedDict` can work on any version, where as `dict` can't. I'll still edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but it seems like you would want to reset the value of `current_k` each time you access a new key

```
dict = {"k1":1, "k2":2, "k3":3}
current=""
for k,v in dict.items():
    current_k=""
    for i in k:
        current_k=i+current_k
    current=str(v)+current_k+current
print(current)
print(current_k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do:

```
print(''.join([a+str(b) for a,b in dict.items()])[::-1])
```

Output:

```
"33k22k11k"
```

But if the values are different from the keys, do:

```
print(''.join([str(b)[::-1]+a for a,b in dict.items()[::-1]]))
```

Comment: doesn't that reverse the values as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this perhaps:

```
dict = {"k1":1, "k2":2, "k3":3}
print("".join(list(reversed([str(v)+"".join(reversed(k)) for k, v in dict.items()]))))
```

**Output:**

```
33k22k11k
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python `map` function to create the reversed string(using f-string) for each key/value pair and then join it.

```
dict1 = {"k1":1, "k2":2, "k3":3}
new_dict =  "".join(map(lambda k, v: f'{k}{v}'[::-1] , dict1.keys(), dict1.values()))
```

Output:

```
33k22k11k
```